# In Android Studio, can I see all my breakpoints listed in a view without starting the debugger?

Tags: android-studio

The title describes the question entirely. I'd like to be able to see (and modify if necessary) all the breakpoints ***before*** starting the debugger.

Can anyone please tell me how I could do that?

Answer (score 10):

It is possible. `CTRL SHIFT F8` is the key combination to bring up the view

Comment: After doing this I found one breakpoint that was not completely removed?

Comment: doesnt work for android studio hedgedog 2023.1.1 on mac os

Comment: Cmd Shift F8 on Mac

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

The `Favorites` item now becomes `Bookmarks`, and still functions the same, to reach out the break points:

- ALT + 2
- From the most left navigation bar hit Bookmarks
- Top menu > View > Tool windows > Bookmarks

[image: enter code here]

---

Original Answer

In Android Studio v.4, you can show the break points from the Favorites by any of:

- `ALT + 2`
- from the most left navigation bar hit `Favorites`
- Top menu > View > Tool windows > Favorites

Comment: there are no favourites in android studio hedgedog 2023.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Update for Android Studio Dolphin -- the breakpoints list seems to have moved to the Bookmarks panel:

[image]

Comment: Still there in Electric Eel Android Studio Electric Eel: 
2022.1.1  built on January 20, 2023

Comment: still there in android studio hedgedog 2023.1.1. great

Answer (score 0):

`CMD + SHIFT + F8` will pop up a window to show the list of breakpoints.